# What is a real world application of Madam Curie's life work?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, radioactivity

As in the title. I know she was working with radioactive atoms and she made huge progress in the field of physics. But where would you find the application of her discoveries in our world? Is it just used in theoretical physics or does it have any meaning to us mortals?

Comment: Are you looking for real-world applications of radioactivity (in which case it's a fairly easy question to answer), or do you mean something else?

Comment: I want to know how does her work help us in real life, not just the application of radioactivity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marie Curie helped to understand the nature of radioactivity, which evidently has subtantial concrete consequences in the production of nuclear energy for instance, but also in the medical applications like X-ray radiography. She was a pioneer in the treatment of cancer using radioactivity.

Comment: +1: Adding to the last sentence: they went waaaay too far in the early 1900s with medical radiation therapy: it was a wonder cure for back pain for example - mainly because it destroyed nerves, along with everything else!